# DriverPack Solution, How To Remove Unwanted Changes

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I recently installed and used DriverPack Solution before I looked it up for any consumer issues. Well, apparently it changes system info to promote itself. How do I remove these changes? Does it still do these changes?

Comment: What changes specifically are you trying to reverse?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Go directly to the manufacturer's site to get drivers and don't install software that promises to find drivers. Also, as Ramhound mentions, unless you tell us WHAT it has changed, we cannot tell you HOW to change it back.

Answer (score 2):

*I assume you already uninstalled DriverPack Solution from your system and are now just needing to remove the system info changes it made to your system. (if you haven't already uninstalled DriverPack, do so before proceeding).*

I've never used DriverPack Solution myself and never intend to, but I'm assuming it has added some unwanted "manufacturer details" and probably a logo to your system info similar to the following:

[image]

To remove any unwanted details/logo/etc from your System Info, do the follwing:

- Click Start Menu and select Run
- Type regedit and hit Enter
- Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > OEMInformation
- Once you select the OEMInformation key, you will see a number of strings over in the right window pane. 
  [image]
- Delete any string that contains any unwanted value that is showing up in your system info. Most likely you will be deleting every string that you see. And that's fine as OEMInformation does not need to contain any strings.
  [image]
- Now reopen your System Information window and you will see that any unwanted info that was there has now been removed.
  [image]

Comment: Under system properties, there is no logo or any evident changes to the system properties. When I went to the OEMInfomation, only the "(Default)" file is there. I wonder if the program does not do this anymore. Or it is using a separate way of promoting itself.

Comment: Can you tell us WHAT DriverPack changed? n8te's answer is good but is based on assumptions because you haven't yet told us WHAT changed. Please edit your question so that we can give you better answers.

Comment: I don't know if it did anything, I was just making sure if it did, what it would be